# What is the reason / logic that "select column by number / occurrence is dis allowed in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Humble request to experienced SO (stackoverflow) users, don't rush and negate the question. I go through a lot and think a lot before asking any question here?

Fetching a column by it's occurrence number / index number will be faster than fetching them by their name which are most often long named.

This question was previously asked as below:
<s>This question is regarding "Why it is not allowed?".</s>
Thus it won't duplicate previously asked questions.

Suppose my table `countries` has two columns first `id_list_countries` and second name `name of country`.

In **MySql**, when i fire

```
"select 0 from countries"
```

it returns column name="0" and rowValues="0"( for as many rows are there in the table)
[image]

In **MS Sql**, when i fire

```
"select 0 from infoes"
```

it returns column name="(no column name)" and rowValues="0"( for as many rows are there in the table)
[image]

I wanted it to return column name="id_list_countries" and rowValues="whatever is"

Why is the query confined so?
Want to know the reason behind this restriction.

Comment: In general, it is not desirable at all to refer to your columns using numerical positions, because column positions can, and often do, change, which could result in breaking any queries which rely on this.  You might be able to do this using dynamic SQL, and you can certainly do this on the application side, e.g. from JDBC.  But, I don't recommend doing it.

Comment: can you post your expected result.

Comment: Why isn't the sun wet? What should be the result of SELECT 3-1?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because why is this behaviour not allowed is not appropriate for this site,

Comment: that's beacause in mysql select 0 from tableName is cosidered as value '0' not column number.      this works same as select  'ABC' in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Such select statement, where you want numbers to represent columns is reserved for selecting scalar values, eg.:

```
select 0
```

would return one row with 0 value.

Analogically, when you want to select scalar value along with all records from table you write:

```
select myColumn, 0 from myTable
```

Thus, `select 0 from myTable` return the value (0) in as many records as there is in a table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i know that. but the question stands in different way. I have modified the question.
To articulate more i will add some related SO questions asked previously.

Answer (score 0):

By `SELECT 0 FROM countries`, you are just selecting 0 value for each row. You can also `SELECT 'foo' FROM countries` and that would just return 'foo' for each row. That's the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 0 AS id_list_countries, 
       name AS rowValues 
from countries
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the syntax, but you may get the approach and implement it on our side.

First as you want to select the first column of your table, so first need to get the first column name from your table schema, for which you may use `information_schema.columns`. By adding filter of table name and `ordinal_position=1`, you'll get your first column name of your table.

```
  set @col = "SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename' AND 'ORDINAL_POSITION'='1'";
```

After that you may create your query by using dynamic sql to get your desired result.

```
 set @query = CONCAT("SELECT ", @c, " FROM yourtable");
 PREPARE stmt FROM @query ;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Hope this will give you your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why would you want to

```
SELECT X(Number)
```

You have there where condition to filter your select

```
SELECT *, name AS rowValues
FROM countries t
WHERE t.id_list_countries = 0 (or any other value you want)
```

The logic behind sql is you select what you want in general and then use filters to filter out the information you dont want from the general select

Comment: And don't use evil `SELECT *`